# Menu javascript/dhtml

Tags: javascript, menu, dhtml

Does anybody know a good free javascript/dhtml menu with vertical alignment, supporting multi-level options, expanding on hover?

Tks in advance

Comment: No :) http://www.message.uk.com/index.php?page=81

Comment: I agree David, but what the client wants.... the client gets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/. especially at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/

Comment: Brilliant. Clean and simple, just what I needed. Tks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [bouquet of 38 jquery menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) some traditional some really bizzare!!!

Comment: jquery was my first attempt and I already tried one great menu built on it but unfortunately I got severe compatibility issues between jquery and some other scripts already in use in the application.